# FSharpTypeFunc.Specialize causing TypeLoadException

Tags: exception, f#

I'm getting the following run-time exception:

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
>   Message=Method 'Specialize' on type [...] tried to implicitly override a method with weaker type parameter constraints.

This inner function appears to be the problem:

```
let getKey (r: IDictionary<_,_>) = 
  match r.TryGetValue(keyCol.Name) with
  | true, k when not (isNull k) -> Some k
  | _ -> None
```

The signature is `IDictionary<string,'a> -> 'a option (requires 'a : null)`. The constraint is propagated from `isNull`.

Looking in ILSpy, `getKey` is compiled to a sub-type of `FSharpTypeFunc` that overrides `Specialize<T>()`.

Is this a bug? I can work around it by boxing `k` in the call to `isNull`, which removes the constraint.

#### EDIT

Here's a full repro:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let isNull = function null -> true | _ -> false
type KeyCol = { Name : string }

let test() =
  seq {
    let keyCol = { Name = "" }
    let getKey (r: IDictionary<_,_>) = 
      match r.TryGetValue(keyCol.Name) with
      | true, k when not (isNull k) -> Some k
      | _ -> None
    getKey (dict ["", box 1])
  }

test() |> Seq.length |> printfn "%d"
```

This is a console app in Visual Studio 2008, targeting .NET 4.0. Strangely, the code works in FSI.

Here's PEVerify output for the assembly:

> [token  0x02000004] Type load failed.
>   [IL]: Error: [D:\TEST\bin\Debug\TEST.exe : Test+test@10[a]::GenerateNext]  [mdToken=0x6000012][offset 0x00000031] Unable to resolve token.
>   2 Error(s) Verifying D:\TEST\bin\Debug\TEST.exe

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a bug, but it would be helpful for you to post a full repro - the code that you've listed compiles fine for me (given some arbitrary definintions for the free identifiers).

Comment: Nice, does look like a bug! Does it disappear with `let inline`?

Comment: @kvb: I added a repro. Looks like wrapping it in a `seq { }` block causes the problem.

Comment: @toyvo: Yes, `inline` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I went ahead and sent it to fsbugs.

Comment: Still doesn't repro for me on VS 2012 RC...  What's your environment?  Does it crash in FSI?  What does PEVerify say?

Comment: @kvb: Sorry, forgot to mention the environment. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sent it to fsbugs and received a reply that it's been fixed.